# Polygon(Quad) to Square Cells

Tags: delphi, graphics, directx, pascal

I am really having a problem with this.

I have a polygon (a quad) which can be any shape. When my mouse is inside the polygon I need to find the x,y values of where my mouse is (inside the quad) as though the poygon were are perfect square. Further explanation; I have a 32x32 texture applied to the polygon and I need to know the x,y of the texture that the mouse is over.
I have some code that works for most shapes but which breaks if TR.Y is less than TL.y for instance.
I have some pretty simple code that tests whether the cursor is inside the polygon (via two triangle tests). But I cannot figure out how to use this to generate an x,y of a virtual square projection.

This problem is killing me. What is the name of operation i am trying to perform? Does anyone know of an explanation where the equations are presented in code form (any kind of code) (rather than just mathematical notation?). Any kind of help would be so appreciated.

I am on the verge of doing a 2nd render with specially formatted textures (each pixel having a unique value) so that I can just colour test to get an approximate x,y match (and precision is something that can be compromised here without causing too much trouble) - but then I will have to work around the DX Lib's attempt to blend and smooth the special texture as it is warped to fill the quad)

**Edit: Code that works for many quad shapes

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It would greatly help if you show us some of your code so we can actually figure out the exact problem.

Comment: I have a 4 Point Rect - that represents a 32x32 tile - The rect is rotated by 45 degrees and then each Y point on the rect has a Height value added (Subtracting the y) that gives an excellent isometric representation (nicely rolling hills, tall mountains and things). The problem isn't a bug in my code but an algorithm failure  -  I need to reverse project a 2D mouse position back to the corresponding x,y of the tile with the 'height' adjustments removed.

Comment: Can't post any *legible* code - user limits(characters & no images) because I have only just made this account.  imgur.com/mhQ04kX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on method - how the texture is drawn at this quad.

If it uses perspective transform Square=>Quad, you have to use matrix of inverse transform Quad=>Square. Short [article](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PerspectiveMappings.pdf)

For linear interpolation approach see [this page](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/596392-uv-coordinate-on-a-2d-quadrilateral/#entry4779201)

Comment: Thankyou - Using the code example in your interpolation link.  Tried to post my results but the Character limit restrictions stopped me. But it is pretty much just a copy for the code in the link you gave me.  Thankyou